# Append new value to existing value of column in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I'm new to Python and MySQL. I have a database named examples in my localhost which has 3 columns.

```
mysql> select * from words;
+----+--------+------------------------------------+
| id | userid | inputs                             |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | aneesh | company's names wow!!! how? etc... |
+----+--------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `inputs` column can contain any characters (so i have given `text` datatype)

I want to write a python code which takes all values (words numbers and special characters) from user input and store it in the `inputs` column in the db without altering the previous values (like append in lists).

eg :-

```
raw_input("Enter Anything:  ")
Enter Anything:  (abcd) awesome!!! @aneesh #tags
```

Now the values in `inputs` column should be

```
company's names wow!!! how? etc... (abcd) is awesome!!! @aneesh #tags
```

Yeah...and I want access those values as words separately so that I can further process it to compare and give error if user enters the word that already exists next time.

Any Idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write and update statement and keep appending it with existing value.

Assuming `v_input` is what you get from user input and for `v_userid`

```
 UPDATE words SET inputs = CONCAT(inputs, v_input) WHERE userid =v_userid
```

Comment: thanks. I does adds words but it shows error for few special characters like ( **'** ) and I used this -- `cur.execute("UPDATE words SET inputs=CONCAT(inputs, '%s')" %(v_input))` .

Comment: I can add every other characters except --( ' ). like if the input is `Ravi's` it will show error. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @Aneeshbhat You might need to escape it. Because, that is special character

Comment: Thanks for your help :). I managed to fix it by adding \"%s\". `UPDATE words SET inputs=CONCAT(inputs, \"%s\")" %(v_input)`